# Is "execution({method name})" required in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

In AOP (Aspect-Oriented Programming), is the "...&& execution({methodName})" tag required, or is the "within(org.{packageName}.{className})" sufficient for the advice to apply to all methods within that class?
For instance, if I've got a method called getId() within a class User, and the advice method in the aspect class has the following tag:

```
@Around("within(org.{packageName}.User)")
```

is the "...&& execution(getId)" part required?

Answer (score 0):

execution() is the primary designator the other ones are only for limiting the matches check [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

Answer (score 0):

In Spring AOP the package + class scope of `within` should be sufficient because Spring AOP only supports method execution pointcuts.

In full AspectJ (can be used within Spring applications via LTW or in non-Spring applications via LTW or CTW) the `within` is not enough because AspectJ supports many more pointcut types such as method call (not the same as execution!), constructor call, constructor execution, static class initialisation, member read/write access etc. If in this case you do not limit the `within` clause to specific pointcut types, all of them will be triggered, leading to a lot of possibly unwanted actions and also a lot of aspect weaving in the first place.

Furthermore, AspectJ can also intercept protected and private methods/constructors, which maybe you do not want. Spring AOP only intercepts public methods and only applies to Spring components. AspectJ applies to any class within its scope, i.e. in LTW scenarios also to 3rd party libraries. Thus, limiting the pointcut scope is important. It is good practice to also do that for Spring AOP aspects because if you ever port them to AspectJ because you need more power in the future, they might do unexpected things. But if you are 100% sure that you will stay within the boundaries of Spring AOP, you are fine with writing pointcuts lazily. `:-)`